# Why does not PHP accept UTF-8 form data?

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm using ajax. I can track the `POST` request and see that data is there in the correct state, however, despite the fact that i have

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

in the beginning of the script, I still get gibberish symbols instead of valid UTF-8 string. What could be the issue?

Here's a part of the html file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
<div id="form-container" role="form" data-toggle="validator" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return false">
```

Here is what my ajax post looks like:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to wrap the post in `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: i need to  process utf-8 string internally not only for displaying

Comment: Do you use html form to POST data? if so, what is HTML's encoding?

Comment: yes, ut-8. see the edit.

Comment: have you got the header statement on both the form input and data output?  Have you looked at the headers with something like curl -I url, to double check?

Comment: Does a bog standard html form work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [mb_detect_encoding();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) instead of trying to force it to UTF-8?

So see if `mb_internal_encoding(mb_detect_encoding($_POST['value']));` gives you any luck?  Or just `echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['value']);` to see what encoding it seems to think it is?  Just a poke in the dark really.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it `mb_detect_encoding` returns `UTF-8`

Comment: Could you provide us with more info about the value in the `$_POST` like what you input on the form, and what it looks like in your script?

Comment: And I was just looking at your HTML.  Why are you using a `<div><div/>` instead of a `<form><form/>` tag?  Just asking, not sure what front end technologies you're using.

Comment: Right, thanks.  The one thing that stands out is obviously the `inputName` parameter being in what appears to be Arabic, I'm not sure if it's meant to be like that as the rest of your post is in roman letters?  To my knowledge UTF-8 supports Arabic characters, but those could be something else.  I'm of Western decent myself and wouldn't know the difference so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: inputname is in georgian. it's meant to be like that. utf-8 supports georgian letters.

Comment: Could you please give the result of :`echo $_POST['inputName']; die();`?
I'm assuming that that's where you're getting the strange characters.

Comment: Then at which point are you seeing the gibberish letters in your php script?